# fetch a text TEXT TYPE from database

Tags: php

actually i have uploaded text to database but when i fetch it and want to use it in html the text format isn't good [as you could see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJp9X.png) i hope i can get some help.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        extract($_GET);
        include('dbconnexion.php');
        try{
            $r=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM GREENWORK WHERE id_gw=$id");
            $r->execute();
            $tbl=$r->fetch();
        }catch(PDOException $err){
            die("error while selectin ".$err->getMessage());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

```html
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <H5>les ingredients :</H5>
  <p>
    <?php print_r($tbl[3]); ?>
  </p>
  <h5>La description:</h5>
  <p>
    <?php echo $tbl[4]; ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What’s wrong with the text, what are you expecting? Please replace the image with text and clarify these two points (by editing the question)

Comment: @AD7six i didn't quite understand what you have said

Comment: I don’t see much scope for misunderstanding there but if you point out _what_ you didn’t understand Its then possible to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text got cut (length-wise), check the size/length of your text-column in the database. If not `VARCHAR` but `TEXT`, try the type `MEDIUMTEXT`/`LONGTEXT`.

If your newlines went missing, try using [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br).

Also please use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL Injection and also escape everything you output (using for example [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars) or for attributes [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities)) to prevent XSS and format issues.

So your output could look something like this:

```
 <?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($tbl[4])); ?>
```